# dpkg error: pycompile: not found

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

I am getting the following error as I try to remove mysql using the above command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

  php5-mysqlnd

Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.

The following extra packages will be installed:

  mysql-server-core-5.5 php5-mysqlnd python-aptdaemon

 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets

  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-uno python3-update-manager
  ubuntu-drivers-common update-manager

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdbd-mysql-perl* libmysqlclient18* mysql-client-5.5* mysql-common*
  mysql-server* mysql-server-5.5* php5-mysql* phpmyadmin*

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-mysqlnd

The following packages will be upgraded:

  mysql-server-core-5.5 python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets

  python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat

  python3-uno python3-update-manager ubuntu-drivers-common update-manager
10 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 8 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
170 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,388 kB of archives.
After this operation, 89.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 354910 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-drivers-common_1%3a0.2.91.9_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-drivers-common.prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-drivers-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-drivers-common_1%3a0.2.91.9_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-drivers-common.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-drivers-common.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../python3-update-manager_1%3a0.196.13_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a0.196.13_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.postinst: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat.prerm: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat.prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat.postinst: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.prerm: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-aptdaemon_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-aptdaemon.postinst: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../update-manager_1%3a0.196.13_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a0.196.13_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.postinst: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.prerm: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.prerm: pyclean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets.postinst: pycompile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python-aptdaemon_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.prerm: pyclean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.postinst: 6: 

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-aptdaemon.postinst: pycompile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Preparing to unpack .../python3-uno_1%3a4.2.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...

/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-uno_1%3a4.2.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.postinst: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-drivers-common_1%3a0.2.91.9_amd64.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a0.196.13_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a0.196.13_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon_1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-uno_1%3a4.2.8-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Can you accept an answer below from many answers, @Kalyanam Rajashree?

Answer (score 63):

Ahhhh, yes.  The venerable "Catch-22" situation of Debian package management.  It boils down to Debian depending on `py3compile` as part of the `libpython3.x` package when that package provides the `py3compile` as well; it's a no-go, there.

I too was bitten by this unable to get `py3compile` working again for I had too deleted the entire /usr/[/local]/lib/python3* directories.

Once done, nothing in Debian package management tool can help you get back to a working Python3 environment.  You must do meat-ball surgery.

Reconstruction of Python3 in Debian entails three critical things:

- Restoring `py3compile` script (for most of you, you already have this)
- Restoring libpython3.7
- Restoring python binary

One could do the RE-copying of /usr[/local]/lib directory from another working Debian host/system. But this time, I shall detail the steps from within the broken host in question (as if you do NOT have another working host).

## Step 1 - Download Packages

Download the impacted Debian packages:

```bash
cd /tmp
apt-get download libpython3.7-minimal
apt-get download python3.7-minimal
apt-get download python3-minimal # (this is important)
apt-get download libpython3.7-stdlib
apt-get download python3.7
```

## Step 2 - Cleanup

Clean up old stuff

```bash
rm -rf /usr[/local]/lib/python3.7*
rm -rf /usr[/local]/bin/python3.7*
update-alternatives --remove python3 /usr[/local]/bin/python3.7
hash -r  # removes cached python3 binary path
```

## Step 3 - Extract files from packages

Let us extract the missing `py3compile`

```bash
cd /tmp
dpkg-deb -x python3-minimal_3.7.3-1_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x python3.7-minimal_3.7.3-2_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.3-2_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.3-2_amd64.deb missing
dpkg-deb -x python3.7_3.7.3-2_amd64.deb missing
```

## Step 4 - Restoring Python, et. al.

Manually install over your root filesystem

```bash
cd /tmp/missing
ls -lR /tmp/missing  # if you are curious about overwriting your HD
sudo cp -rpfv /tmp/missing/*  /
```

## Step 5 - Verification

Start up Python3

```py
python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Test import and show version

```py
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>>
>>> quit()
```

## Step 6 - Clean up ourselves

```bash
rm -rf /tmp/missing
```

## Step 7 - Officially reinstall Python via Debian APT

```bash
dpkg -s -a  | grep  reinstreq
# Any listing also needs to be reinstalled along with python3
apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

Most likely, you got MANY packages that are in that stuck state of "reinstreq" state.

```bash
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
# (MANY PACKAGES FAILED TO BE INSTALLED)
```

At this point, you will have to manually reinstall each and every one of those listed by `apt-get autoremove`...

```bash
apt-get install --fix-broken --reinstall <list-of-many-failed-packages>
```

## Last Step - Reinstalling impacted half-state Debian packages

Let me guess, you got the following error:

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for XXXXXX
```

I will tell you that you probably had a newer Debian release in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for awhile, it went all down south (bad), and took that newer release out of the `sources.list` file (in effort to revert back to a 'stable' release): that's not an unrecoverable thing to me here, just that you jerked the Debian package database around a bit there ... rather brusquely.

The resolution of the last step entails a restoration and stabilization of the Debian package management database by reinstalling nearly everything.  I will detail it later but the link to follow is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266450/how-to-fix-e-internal-error-no-file-name-for-libc6).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a thousand times, as it saved me no end of further pain....

Comment: @kenorb could always accept this answer.  Still waiting.

Comment: Man.. this has saved from spending another 8 hrs fixing my pythons..

Comment: Ok, this guy just freed me from a world of pain and eternal damnation. I totally concur with Derrell, I wish I could upvote this a thousand times. I wonder why this is not the accepted answer?? Thanks a ton @JohnGreene!

Just a quick note, in Ubuntu 16.04 "dpkg -s -a  | grep  reinstreq" didn't seem to work. I worked around it with "dpkg -l | grep iFR".

Comment: Works with Python 3.9, because it’s what i do now.  ;-)

Comment: Great sir, you need a donate link in your profile! This answer has improved my life quality!

Comment: Let me also express my grattitude for this solution, as well as add some keywords, as in my case the original issue was "Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding" and I encountered it on Raspbian.

Comment: I had to ensure all subversions of python3 were all the same (i.e. python3-minmal's deb package was 3.8.2-0ubuntu2, I had to install python3.8 packages) Thank you for the awesome answer!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing answer! I've spent about 3 hours trying to fix my system, trying suggestions from numerous other answers on Ubuntu SE, but nothing worked until this. And all because I accidentally overwrote /usr/bin/python3.11 with a symbolic link, and then the python3.11 package wouldn't reinstall because python3.11 was missing!

Comment: Can't believe this isn't the accepted answer!

Comment: I have tried to alert @kalyanam about this.

Comment: This SAVED me today

Comment: Still saving people in 2024

Answer (score 23):

> py3compile: not found

The `py3compile` command is part of `python3-minimal` package which seems to be broken.

To fix the issue, try the following:

- Correct a system with broken dependencies in place by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get  -f install
  ```
- Reconfigure all unpacked, but unconfigured packages by:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  ```
- If above won't help, try reinstalling `python3-minimal` package by:

  ```
  sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal
  ```

  Alternatively run:

  ```
  apt-get download python3-minimal
  sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb
  sudo apt install -f
  ```

  Or download the [`.pkg` file from kernel.org](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/) and install from the file by:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i python3-minimal_*.deb
  ```

Then make sure that `py3compile` and `py3clean` commands are runnable and are accessible from your `PATH` variable.

Comment: sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal is the key thing after all the purging and cleaning. As mentioned if you cant run py3compile and py3clean dont try anything else til that is fixed. Thanks !

Comment: least dangerous solution in my opinion. my ansible dependency was making dpkg fail for each other installation because of the post installation, script that required ppy3compile. 
`sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal` did the trick and got the environment to work again. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Despite py3compile and py3clean being present in /usr/bin/, my Lubunutu 16.10 shell (tcsh) kept complaining that py3compile was not there. After hours of frustration, I discovered that the first line in pycompile was:

`! /usr/bin/env python`

or something like that, which referred to Python2.7 on my system. Changing that to point to Python 3 with:

`! /usr/local/bin/python3`

suddenly made py3compile visible!

Turns out that the shell said py3compile did not exist even when it was in its path or was directly executed with "*/usr/bin/py3compile*" when py3compile referred to Python2.7. The shell did not even complain about the Python version or anything, it just claimed py3compile itself did not exist!

I got into this mess because I wanted to remove and reinstall Python 3.5, upon doing which I discovered that there is still a Python 3, which I then discovered comes from a python-minimal, which I tried to remove and reinstall. The python-minimal would not reinstall, even after I tried every thing I could find on the net and every package manager. They all would complain about py3compile missing. Now I discovered this fix for py3compile.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2
```

Because:

```
# head -1 `which pycompile`
#! /usr/bin/python2
```

Answer (score 1):

By shear luck and banging around, I found a simpler method

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3.11-minimal
```

or replace your version of python as nessisary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First remove packages not more needed:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Clears out the local repository of retrieved package files

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Remove the packages(mysql-client is not installed):

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-common
```

Comment: I tried all the commands mentioned. It still gives the same error at the end.

Comment: I tried all the commands mentioned. It still gives the same error at the end. In fact I am getting the same error whenever I try to install or remove anything(seriously, nothing is getting installed or removed) in my ubuntu.

Comment: It's a more general problem, I think is related to dpkg.

Comment: Related to dpkg. Yes it is. What can I do ?

Comment: Now, I uninstalled python(found many errors though). Now if I try uninstalling mysql using the same command, I am not getting the old list of deb files, instead I am getting only one name. It is libgksu2-0.

Answer (score 0):

Try

apt install --reinstall hplip hplip-data

followed by

apt install --reinstall python3

Answer (score 0):

I landed in this situation because I accidentally forgot the syntax of `update-alternatives` and ran the following command

```
# Don't do this!!!
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python 20
# Should have been
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 20
```

After this even the `python3` command was not working

I didn't want to go through re-installing the entire Python3.6 while I had only messed up the binary. So I was looking for a way to get the binary but whether I try `apt` or `apt-get` or download the dpkg as mentioned in other answers I always ended up with `pycompile` not working since it can't find Python3

Thankfully I noticed that there is a `/usr/bin/python3.6m` which is mostly the same as the existing Python version as per [What's the difference between python3.<x> and python3.<x>m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589655/whats-the-difference-between-python3-x-and-python3-xm) so I just did

```
cp python3.6m python3.6
```

And it worked. I was able to use the python3 command again

After this `dpkg` still considered python3 as unconfigured so I had to run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error with just:

```
(cd /usr/bin ; ln -s python2.7 python2 -v)
```

Checking **/usr/bin/pycompile** source, found that the bang point to *python2* and was not available.