# What's the difference between python3.<x> and python3.<x>m

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

- What does the **`m`** stand for in `python3.6m` ?
- How does it differ to non **`m`** version?
- In which case would I prefer to use `python3.6m` rather than `python3.6`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> What does the `m` stand for in `python3.6m`?

It signifies that Python was configured `--with-pymalloc` which enables a specialized implementation for allocating memory that's faster than the system `malloc`.

> How does it differ to non `m` version?

The non `m` version is, obviously, not configured with it.

> In which case would I prefer to use `python3.6m` rather than `python3.6`?

Probably most usefull when writing `C` extensions, in general it shouldn't be something you should worry about.

Comment: This answer sounds satisfying, but not when my machine tells me that both executables are exactly 4576440 bytes in size. (pretty clean ubuntu 18.04 server install). I demand to know why they are at least not symlinked to each other. waste of disk. grumble.

Comment: And yes they have the same SHA1 hash too.

Comment: i have noticed that they have different header files, that may be the difference

Comment: @StevenLu app may choose to behave differently depending on its invocation name. not sure about this particular case, though

Comment: if python m is faster, why would one not use that exclusively?

Comment: @StevenLu On my system they *are* the same: `ls -i python3.7 python3.7m` reports `8943110 python3.7  8943110 python3.7m`; same inode, so same file. It's a hard link. I presume this is done so that `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7m` works?

Comment: sweet! @MartinTournoij